# AWS S3 Bucker with WORM policy and replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created an AWS S3 bucket that is configured to use WORM pattern (Write Once Read Many), now I wish to enable its replica but I got the following message:

[image]

Great but when I go to the contact where should I go? I don't have technical support with the base plan:

*"Technical support is unavailable under Basic Support Plan"*

So how can I solve this?

Comment: Create a new bucket with the object lock enabled from the start!?

Comment: I've tried it... but when you go to add the replica it says to contact support as well